# App will not open on android device

Tags: android

I created a very simple app in eclipse and when i go to run it on my device (g2x) it installs but the app doesnt open. i also found the app .apk in my phone and reinstalled it but it wont open after the install.

> [2012-10-17 10:20:44 - Simple button] Performing sync
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:44 - Simple button] Automatic Target Mode: using device '0428000541a032d7'
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:44 - Simple button] Uploading Simple button.apk onto device '0428000541a032d7'
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:44 - Simple button] Installing Simple button.apk...
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:47 - Simple button] Success!
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:47 - Simple button] \Simple button\bin\Simple button.apk installed on device
>   [2012-10-17 10:20:47 - Simple button] Done!

this is the consol code from eclipse

```
10-17 10:45:00.048: D/Beautiful Widgets(4100)(6043): WidgetRefreshService
10-17 10:45:00.048: D/test(6043): else
10-17 10:45:00.097: D/dalvikvm(6043): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 48% free 3405K/6471K, external 26K/512K, paused 2ms+1ms
10-17 10:45:00.117: D/dalvikvm(6043): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 377K, 48% free 3405K/6471K, external 51K/512K, paused 18ms
10-17 10:45:10.197: D/AndroidRuntime(19168): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-17 10:45:10.197: I/AndroidRuntime(19168): Heap size: -Xmx48m
10-17 10:45:10.197: D/AndroidRuntime(19168): CheckJNI is OFF
10-17 10:45:10.197: D/dalvikvm(19168): creating instr width table
10-17 10:45:10.347: D/AndroidRuntime(19168): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-17 10:45:10.357: D/AndroidRuntime(19168): Shutting down VM
10-17 10:45:10.357: D/dalvikvm(19168): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 70% free 308K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+0ms


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simple.button"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Mainscreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mainscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.gup" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the manifest, is this corect? cause noting has really changed besides this so far.

Comment: im pretty new to this.. how do i get to that

Comment: so i found LogCat and LogCat(deprecated) which one ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That's from logcat, yes, but it doesn't seem to be the relevant part. What shows up in logcat when you try to run the app? Can you run your app in an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when installing application from Eclipse, the default application `Activity`, which has an `android.intent.action.MAIN` action, is opened. Probably your app is missing this `Activity` by accident. Go to the manifest file and make sure the main `Activity` has this kind of intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thankyou very much, it runs now. but.. it crashes on startup.

Comment: @Guparasti, That's probably another issue.